# Why PHP 7.1.3 script is not running on Apache 2.4.25?

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

I am trying to make a php script run to make the first test on the browser but it doesn't work. When I try to open the link it shows me the following:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Currently I have PHP 7.1.3 installed and Apache 2.4.25 in a Amazon VM with AMI. And the file phpinfo.php contains the same showed above by the browser.

Below some commands to confirm.

php -v
PHP 7.1.3 (cli) (built: Mar 26 2017 15:36:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon)
Server built:   Jan 19 2017 16:55:49

In the file http.conf I took the following actions:

## Updated a section:

```
`<IfModule dir_module>`
    `DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php index.html`
`</IfModule>`
```

## Inserted some lines:

```
`<FilesMatch \.php$>`
`   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php`
`</FilesMatch>`
`<FilesMatch \.phps$>`
`   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source`
`</FilesMatch>`
`AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps`
```

I would appreciate some help on this. Please let me know if I can provide any other information that might help on solving this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try running it from the bash line?

Comment: Might just need to add `LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so` to the apache config.

Comment: Instructions can be found [here](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php). Make sure you've followed all the steps. Also, I hope those backticks are just transcription errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it seems I cannot not complete this step LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so. After searching in all the server for this file libphp7.so and libphp*.so it was not created. I followed these instructions http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/php.html to install php 7.1.3. Is there an specific instruction to create this module in particular?

Comment: If you want to compile PHP from source code then it's a fairly different question. Surely, the Apache module is not mandatory (you need the `--with-apxs2` switch).

Comment: Thanks for your support after recompiling it worked